# php preg_match, not working for validating URL's

Tags: php, windows, apache, preg-match

Ihave a PHP preg_match regex which is :

```
#^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.|//)*(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d{1,5}))?([A-Z0-9_-]|\.|\/|\?|\#|=|&|%)*$#i
```

The problem is when I try to match any URL ending with .com&& , it returns true, but as expected it should return false, what could be possibly wrong with it?

I am using it as:

```
    function isValidURL($url) {
        if (preg_match("#^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.|//)*(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d{1,5}))?([A-Z0-9_-]|\.|\/|\?|\#|=|&|%)*$#i", $url)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and accessing it as:

```
$URL = $_GET['url'];
echo var_dump(isValidURL($URL));
```

Now if I open the page as `/url.php?url=http://www.google.com` it returns true, if I open page as `/url.php?url=http://www.google.com**` it returns false.  If I open the page as `/url.php?url=http://www.google.com&&` it returns true but it should return false as .com&& is not a valid TLD.

Answer (score 3):

Your bit here at the end...

```
([A-Z0-9_-]|\.|\/|\?|\#|=|&|%)*
```

is what's matching the ampersands. What you probably want to do is require a prefixed question mark if there's a query string:

```
(\?([A-Z0-9_-]|\.|\/|\?|\#|=|&|%)*)?
```

However, there's a better way to do this in PHP 5.2+:

```
var_dump(filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: filter_var won't validate .me domains ! thats the bug!